# Django based Microblog

Tags: django, notifications, blogs, user-profile

I would like to build a notification system that will give updates to the user regarding the following events all at the same place

> 1. When somebody sends a private message
> 2. When somebody comments on their blog
> 3. When somebody comments on their post
> 4. If a user has selected to 'follow' somebody then give them updates about their activity

I would also like to make a generic MicroBlog that will give random updates about things people are doing like, blogs they have written, tutorials they have written, a new question that has been posted.

I have individual models for blogs, questions, comments and so on. But I do not know how too implement the notification system. I have implemented the system in **Django**

Comment: Have you seen Django's signaling mechanism?

Comment: I had asked this question a long time back, and I tried out different apps that have been suggested but in the end nothing seemed to work out. At the end I developed my custom solution using django signals

Comment: That's what I was wondering, you actually didn't need any third party app for your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by you choice of words, I'd say you haven't yet dived into [django-notification](http://jtauber.com/django-notification/) or [django-notify](http://code.google.com/p/django-notify/): both of these will likely scratch your itch.

Comment: Yes you are pretty correct I have not dived into either of them. I have come across them, read the documentation but ended up with nothing. The basic reason is that I am totally new to Django and have been unable to integrate such apps. I know it sounds like a novice but if you could point me to a tutorial that could tell me how to integrate an application like django-notification then ot would really help me. To tell you really one who is working on django for the first time can find it a daunting task

Comment: @Sachin: you could check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609775/how-do-i-display-notifications-from-django-notification): it seems to have some good starters in it. The Pinax-code they refer to also has a [decent tutorial](http://fernandoacorreia.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/exploring-pinax-part-7/) for it.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial it really helped

Answer (score 1):

see [django-notification](http://jtauber.com/django-notification/)

> The project aims to provide a Django app for this sort of
>   functionality. This includes:
>
> submission of notification messages by other apps notification
>   messages on signing in notification messages via email (configurable
>   by user) notification messages via feed

Comment: I fail to understand how it links with the user profiles, where and how I can display the notifications. Actually I am a beginner and it is really difficult, because I just don't have the feel of the whole thing

Comment: I cannot help you to get a feeling for the whole thing. Only u can by reading and trying. So try and if u fail, come back with more specific questions. I wrote some basic code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829926/reusable-application-for-django-site-wide-announcements-that-displays-a-message/1829956#1829956